# How to convert Oracle NUMBER Primary Key to SQL Server For Ado.Net Consumption

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ado.net

This could be a composite question, as I may not fully understand the issue.

I am scraping data from an Oracle Apex Query interface and storing the results in a local SQL Server instance so that local applications can take advantage of the data.

The Oracle database I am pulling from uses primary keys that are defined as NUMBER data types (without precision or scale defined).  What data type should I use on the SQL Server end to store an Oracle NUMBER field?

Most of the documentation I have found states to store a NUMBER data field in SQL Server as a Float, but this is not helpfull since many of these NUMBER fields represent primary keys (using a floating point value as a primary key is a bad idea).

I had toyed with using DECIMAL(38,38) in Sql Server to store the Oracle value, but when you attempt to set an ADO.NET SqlParameter (Such as on an SqlCommand) with a type of DECIMAL(38,38) with a value you will get an Arithmetic Overflow error, as it will always fully expand the SCALE.  E.G. the number 23425 would expand to 23425.00000000000000000000000000000000000000 and would give an overflow error because it has used up more storage than is available in the precision of the data type of the SqlParameter.

Comment: Doesn't `decimal(38, 38)` in SQL server mean a number that has 38 with all 38 digits to the right of the decimal point? So it would never hold a number greater than or equal to one.

Comment: +1 Yes, I was hoping that the illustration of something that can't be done that I wanted to do would job someone's memory about how to accomplish the same thing.  A Number data type in Oracle without a precision or scale acts like a Decimal(38,38) where the actual number of digits to the right of the decimal place can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, when no precision or scale are specified NUMBER is [decimal floating point type.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#sthref120) Not to be confused with a binary floating point type.

Oracle also supports decimal fixed point by specifying precision and optionally scale to NUMBER, i.e. `NUMBER(11,2)` which will would be good for holding US dollar values to $999,999,999.99.

SQL Server supports fixed point decimal with the [DECIMAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) type and floating point binary with [float and real](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) Neither of SQL Servers fixed point decimal or floating point binary data types will hold all possible values of Oracles decimal floating point type (NUMBER) with out either error or loss of information.

If you are dealing with an Oracle database were all numeric data is held in NUMBER type without precision or scale and some **data** is of integer values, like surrogate primary keys and some **data** is fixed point values, such as US Dollars and other **data** is truly widely varying in scale and only needs approximate values held, then you will need to map data types on a column by column basis.

Comment: This was what I ended up implementing.  It is sad that there is no data type that maps directly to "NUMBER".  Thanks for clarifying the decimal / binary floating point distinction.  I knew that was part of the issue but I didn't know how to word it properly.

Comment: So... if the source Oracle data in a `NUMBER` column was truly all integer values, would `NUMERIC(38,0)` accommodate it on the SQL Server side?

Comment: If the source Oracle data could be put in Oracle `NUMBER(38)` then it would fit into a SQL Server `NUMERIC(38, 0)`. But `10^50` is an integer, in the math sense, would fit into Oracle `NUMBER` but not SQL Server `NUMERIC(38, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a comment, it seems hard to believe the values would be anything but ints, but with that being said....

It sounds like the real question is, is this an int or a float?  Because the easiest solution would be to convert it to an int.

You can find out by doing a query on the source table to see if the decimal value is always zero, if so it is an int.

I don't use Oracle but I believe the correct flavor of SQL would be this:

```
select id_column
  from theTable
 where id_column - trunc(id_column,0) <> 0
   and rownum <= 1
```

If you get no rows, you have integers.  If you get even one row, they are using floats.

If for some strange reason they are floats, you can still convert them to ints. Do a query to find out the highest precision, and then multiple by 10^x, where x is the max precision.  This gives you ints again.

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue, but it is a good comment.  I have built a reader that parses the csv results of the queries from oracle and maps them to an SQL type using a column mapping reolver class that has access to the column names and data types.  If I pick and choose which NUMBER columns are treated differently then I must update my code/configuration every time a primary key is added to the schema.  I am more looking to see if a one to one mapping exists that can be used as a primary key.